# boost::lexical_cast without runtime libraries

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast, microsoft-runtime-library

I'm in a situation where I would like to use boost::lexical_cast, but cannot make use of C/C++ runtime libraries, and thus cannot use lexical_cast. I don't know Boost extremely well, but I have seen the use of blocks such as:

```
#ifdef BOOST_NO_STRINGSTREAM
#include <strstream> 
#else  
#include <sstream>  
#endif
```

and am wondering if there might be a #define to use so that Boost doesn't depend on said libraries.

If there's a specific place in the Boost documentation that explains possible preprocessor options, that would be much appreciated as well, as I can't seem to find it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) for configuring Boost for special cases.

`Boost.Lexical_Cast` depends at least on `<string>`, `<istream>` and `<ostream>` from standard library. Possibly more. I don't think you can remove such dependencies by simply reconfiguring something.

Comment: I'll check out Boost.Config. I was hoping, since for example boost::container::string works in my environment, that the configuration would be able to use Boost replaces for the standard library.